# What are the different realms in the Lego World?

Tags: the-lego-movie

During the backstory in the Lego Movie Wildstyle says Lord Business separated the world into a number of different realms and they flash up. Later during the movie there is a world map that shows the realms.

What are the different realms that the world was split into?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you've unaccepted my answer?

Answer (score 34):

Lord Business' map (in his boardroom) shows the Lego Movie universe and its various realms:

> - **Atlantis**
> - **Bricksburg**
> - **Cape Space**
> - **Dino Island**
> - **Forest of Obsolete Products**
> - **Middle Zealand**
> - **The Old West**
> - **Pharaoh's Quest**
> - **Pirate's Cove**
> - **Technic Mecha Mine**
> - **Viking's Landing**
> - **Vladek's Realm**

We also know that there's a hidden realm called '**Cloud-Cuckoo Land**' in the clouds above the Forest realm.

---

Additionally,

- There seems to be another (unnamed) landmass to the south
- **Octan HQ** also appears to be listed as its own separate realm.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to go ahead an speculate that the image of the BIONICLE sets from 2001 'belong' to The Forest of Obsolete Products. Well, that or the Technic Mecha Mine.

Comment: Cloud-Cuckoo Land is where Unikitty lives.

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley Not to mention the rest of the [Cloudcuckoolanders](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Cloudcuckoolander) ;)

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley - In the junk-box :-( http://i.stack.imgur.com/bDh2z.png